# Телеграмм бот не отвечает

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Есть Telegram bot с использованием вебхук. Сделала по работающему образцу , подставив свои значения. Сертификаты выдал провайдер, на сервере которого мой сайт. Я их проверила, оценка А. Однако бот не реагирует, хотя и ошибок не выдает.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import telebot, time
server= Flask(__name__)
bot_token="мой токен"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(2)
IP="https://api.telegram.org/bot мой токен/setWebhook?url=https://24komissaro2.ru:8443/"
bot.set_webhook(url="https://api.telegram.org/bot мой токен/setWebhook? 
url=https://24komissaro2.ru:8443/")
@server.route("/ ", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    r = request.get_json()
    if "message" in r.keys():
        chat_id = r["message"]["chat"]["id"]
    if "text" in r["message"]:
        text_mess = r["message"]["text"]
    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Какая то не понятная проблема", parse_mode='HTML')
        return "ok", 200

if text_mess == '/start':
  bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Привет WebHook")
  return "ok", 200

server.run()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код, отступы разъехались и код перестал быть рабочим

Comment: в `url` точно должно быть `https://24komissaro2.ru:8443/`?

Comment: в IP и url так и есть: мой токен?

Comment: @Jack_oS, нет, там токен бота, он уникален, показывать его нельзя

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/webhook_examples/webhook_flask_echo_bot.py . Так же вы можете проверить информацию о хуке с помощью https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getWebhookInfo

Answer (score 2):

Начнём с построения бота -
Что у Вас правильно -

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
```

Все остальное неправильно -

Далее нужно создать хендлер -

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) #Отвечает на команду start в чате
```

И теперь создаём функцию с ответом

```
def start_command(message): #Обязательно (message)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет WebHook") #Тут так же не забываем про message
    return "ok", 200
```

И в конце нужно обязательно запустить бота!!

```
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Вместе -

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет WebHook")
    return "ok", 200

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Теперь можете добавлять вебхуки

Comment: а минусы откуда... если это неочевидно, то отписывайтесь в комментариях пожалуйста. Плюс участник новый относительно.

Comment: Любители минусовать наверно