# Telegram-бот на Python, который проверяет домашки

Tags: python, api, telegram, бот

Учусь в Яндексе, есть задание создать телеграм-бота, который будет посылать запрос на сервер и писать мне сообщение о статусе домашки. Либо принята ревьюером, либо не принята.
Никак не можем понять в чем дело и почему программа не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чём проблема.
Сразу скажу - наставник написал, что с решением всё ок! Моя цель именно понять, почему вылезает ошибка и не запускается программа, а не изменить решение. Оно проходит все тесты. Не предлагайте, пожалуйста, иные варианты решения. Кое-кто писал даже, что на других компах запускается прога. Возможно, что то недоустановлено. `requirements` установлены. `dotenv` тоже загружен!
Содержимое файла `.env` - без пробелов и кавычек. Это текстовый файл обычный.

Скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "homework.py", line 67, in <module> 
main() File "homework.py", line 51, in main bot = 
telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN) File 
"C:\Users\irina\Desktop\Dev\api_sp1_bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\telegram\bot.py", line 133, in init self.token = 
self._validate_token(token) File 
"C:\Users\irina\Desktop\Dev\api_sp1_bot\venv\lib\site- 
packages\telegram\bot.py", line 195, in _validate_token if any(x.isspace() 
for x in token): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable –
```

Код:

```
import os
import time
import requests

import requests
import telegram
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()


PRAKTIKUM_TOKEN = os.getenv('PRAKTIKUM_TOKEN')
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
CHAT_ID = os.getenv('CHAT_ID')
URL = 'https://praktikum.yandex.ru/api/user_api/homework_statuses/'

def parse_homework_status(homework):
    homework_name = homework.get('homework_name')
    status = homework.get('status')
    if homework_name is None or status is None:
        return 'Что-то пошло не так'
    elif status == 'rejected':
        verdict = 'К сожалению в работе нашлись ошибки.'
    elif status == 'approved':
        verdict = 'Ревьюеру всё понравилось, можно приступать к следующему уроку.'
    return f'У вас проверили работу "{homework_name}"!\n\n{verdict}'


def get_homework_statuses(current_timestamp):
    if current_timestamp is None:
        current_timestamp = int(time.time())
    headers = {'Authorization': f'OAuth {PRAKTIKUM_TOKEN}'}
    params = {'from_date': current_timestamp}
    try:
        homework_statuses = requests.get(
            url=URL,
            headers=headers,
            params=params
        )
        return homework_statuses.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Ошибка у бота {e}')
        return dict()


def send_message(message, bot_client):
    return bot_client.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=message)


def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
    current_timestamp = int(time.time())  
    while True:
        try:
            new_homework = get_homework_statuses(current_timestamp)
            if new_homework.get('homeworks'):
                send_message(parse_homework_status(new_homework.get('homeworks')[0]), bot)
            current_timestamp = new_homework.get('current_date', current_timestamp) 
            time.sleep(300)  

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Ошибка у бота: {e}')
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: лучше код выложить сюда и текст ошибки, а не картинку

Comment: Так по ссылке же доступен код, и его можно скопировать
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "homework.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "homework.py", line 51, in main
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\irina\Desktop\Dev\api_sp1_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 133, in __init__
    self.token = self._validate_token(token)
  File "C:\Users\irina\Desktop\Dev\api_sp1_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\bot.py", line 195, in _validate_token
    if any(x.isspace() for x in token):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Вы понимаете в чём ошибка?

Comment: Странный вопрос, тогда зачем бы мне здесь что то спрашивать? нет, конечно. Понимаю, что консоль пишет, что что-то не так с инициализацией бота. Но, насколько вижу, всё прописано правильно насчёт инициализации.

Comment: Так вот, а программа отвечает что рядок `if any(x.isspace() 
for x in token):` пустой и с ним ничего сделать нельзя. Попробуйте сделать что-то с пустотой) `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Это рядок не из моего кода. Я не понимаю, что нужно исправить именно в моём коде. а не в каких-то доп фалах

Comment: Да, это не Ваш код! Но Вы пытаетесь вытянуть токен неизвесный!

Answer (score 2):

Во первых в ошибке пишет что с пустотой нельзя ничего сделать - `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`
Во вторых - у Вас неправильное построение Telegram бота -

1. **Никогда** не используйте вечный цикл в боте (`while True`)
2. Запускайте бота не этой (`if __name__ == '__main__':    main()`) командой, **а этой (`bot.polling(none_stop=True)`) командой** *(раньше было `if __name__ == '__main__':    bot.polling(none_stop=True)`)*
3. Пример построения бота - [Телеграмм бот не отвечает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219561/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82/1219623#1219623)

Вы используете библиотеку `telegram` для построения ботов, но я Вам советую `telebot` (https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/) и напишу Вам бота на `telebot` -

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('здесь токен бота, получить его можна в ботфазере')
current_timestamp = int(time.time())  

@bot.message_handler(commands=['hw']) #Запускаем бота при написании `/hw` в чате
def start_command(message):
    new_homework = get_homework_statuses(current_timestamp)
    if new_homework.get('homeworks'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message)       #text=message
    current_timestamp = new_homework.get('current_date', current_timestamp) 

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

А ещё у Вас два раза импортировано `requests` (но это мелочи (╹ڡ╹))

```
import time
import requests

import requests
import telegram
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```